# Text Box in MS Access Form not working for 1 user

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've inherited a complex MS Access system we use to track manufacturing defects. It has a front-end file placed on user's computers and another file as the backend hosted on our NAS and linked to the front end.

One particular form lists all defects (rows of a particular table on the backend), and is filtered by another form that is displayed at the same time. The footer for this first form contains a text box whose Control Source is `=Count([ID])` and a second whose Control Source is `=Round(Sum([Loss units]),0)` (both of which are columns in this form). The problem is that these boxes work for everyone in my company except one person. When I open the front-end on my or anyone else's computer, it shows correctly. On this one user's computer, the same file doesn't show any text in those boxes but otherwise appears to work fine. Filtering works, and the defect data is correctly populated, but it's not showing the number of items or the total units lost. Clicking on these text boxes makes a 0 appear in the second text box, which disappears if you click anywhere else, though nothing is listed as an On Click Event for these boxes.

I can try other actions or provide more information if requested. I suspect this might be some sort of default setting in Access that isn't being changed when I delete his local file and replace it with a fresh copy, but I can't find anything that would cause this.

Edit, additional symptom: There are a number of forms with charts in this file, and none of them are processing data either. But the data is still showing up in the main table.

Comment: Is this front end specifically written for that user?  If not, just delete his and grab someone else's copy.  Maybe the file went corrupt somehow.

Comment: Each user has their own copy of the front-end file, but I've already deleted his and replaced it with a copy of the one that works on my machine.

Comment: What about grabbing the name of the second box, searching through the VBA, and then debugging with a break point?  Can you trace any 'auto-populates' that way?  There has to be a `Focus` or `Dirty` or `On_click` somewhere making the number 0 appear then disappear.

Comment: Not found in the entire "project" VBA (I assume we're talking the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications that opens when double clicking Modules?), and the only code for the form is related to formatting some hyperlinks on mouseover. Nothing is supposed to happen with the text box when clicked; I think that's just a quirk of whatever is causing this bug. The only thing I can find that sets this text box's value is the Control Source property I mentioned above, and everything under the Event tab of the Property Sheet is blank.

Comment: Kind of a long-shot, but are you positive everyone is using the same version of Access, and the same revision of that version?  We had something similar where it ended up one person was using the Run-time version of Access and everyone else had the full version.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Good idea, although when I checked he was using the full version of Access 2010, and that was the process and file being used to open the accdb. I found another symptom (no charts are displaying) and am updating the main text right now.

Comment: If you're showing there is nothing wrong with end user's config vs your own config in Access, maybe try the repair feature in the programs and features?  Did his use to work and isn't?  Or is he a new employee?  Does a user need to added to the back end of this by chance?

Comment: Apologies, but this particular user is out until Monday. Repairing Office is a good idea and I'll try as soon as I can. His used to work and then didn't. Backend permissions are set correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of updates. This particular user is senior in my company and has other priorities currently. If and when he lets me repair MS Office for him, I'll update here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User "doesn't know what [he] did" but the problem is resolved. It very likely was fixed because of rebooting. My life lesson out of this: even for senior members of the organization, stick with the IT mantra "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"